# Check internet connection for sign up button in android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Just like the <kbd>Log in</kbd> button, it shou­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ld display an alert dialog if an internet connection isn't available and the user taps on the  <kbd>Sign up</kbd>  button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog is in the app as of version 1.0.6 coming out later today, thanks!

Comment: Release 1.0.6 then to verify if it's fixed!

Comment: Can see dialog in 1.0.6 version. Fixed!

Comment: A problem with this is that it incorrectly tells you that there is no internet connection if you are using something nonstandard, like Bluetooth tethering or Ethernet, even though the app itself does work once logged in.